# PIC18F26J50: timer0 issues

Tags: pic, timer

I'm implementing timer routines using timer0. The goal is to have a 1ms timer routine so I can use it for general proposes. The problem is that I'm getting a 13kHz waveform in RA6 and I intended to have a 1kHz waveform. Compiler is C18.

Relevant part of the circuit is this:
[image: Circuit]

Here is the code:

testTimer.c

```
#include "processor.h"
#include "defs.h"

#include "clock.h"
#include "timer.h"

// PIC18F26J50 Configuration Bit Settings
// 'C' source line config statements
#include <p18F26J50.h>

// CONFIG1L
#pragma config WDTEN = OFF // Watchdog Timer (Disabled - Controlled by SWDTEN bit)
#pragma config PLLDIV = 2 // PLL Prescaler Selection bits (Divide by 2 (8 MHz oscillator input))
#pragma config STVREN = OFF // Stack Overflow/Underflow Reset (Disabled)
#pragma config XINST = OFF // Extended Instruction Set (Disabled)

// CONFIG1H
#pragma config CPUDIV = OSC1 // CPU System Clock Postscaler (No CPU system clock divide)
#pragma config CP0 = OFF // Code Protect (Program memory is not code-protected)

// CONFIG2L
#pragma config OSC = INTOSCPLL // Oscillator (INTOSCPLL)
#pragma config T1DIG = OFF // T1OSCEN Enforcement (Secondary Oscillator clock source may not be selected)
#pragma config LPT1OSC = OFF // Low-Power Timer1 Oscillator (High-power operation)
#pragma config FCMEN = OFF // Fail-Safe Clock Monitor (Disabled)
#pragma config IESO = OFF // Internal External Oscillator Switch Over Mode (Disabled)

// CONFIG2H
#pragma config WDTPS = 32768 // Watchdog Postscaler (1:32768)

// CONFIG3L
#pragma config DSWDTOSC = INTOSCREF// DSWDT Clock Select (DSWDT uses INTRC)
#pragma config RTCOSC = INTOSCREF// RTCC Clock Select (RTCC uses INTRC)
#pragma config DSBOREN = OFF // Deep Sleep BOR (Disabled)
#pragma config DSWDTEN = OFF // Deep Sleep Watchdog Timer (Disabled)
#pragma config DSWDTPS = G2 // Deep Sleep Watchdog Postscaler (1:2,147,483,648 (25.7 days))

// CONFIG3H
#pragma config IOL1WAY = OFF // IOLOCK One-Way Set Enable bit (The IOLOCK bit (PPSCON<0>) can be set and cleared as needed)
#pragma config MSSP7B_EN = MSK7 // MSSP address masking (7 Bit address masking mode)

// CONFIG4L
#pragma config WPFP = PAGE_63 // Write/Erase Protect Page Start/End Location (Write Protect Program Flash Page 63)
#pragma config WPEND = PAGE_WPFP// Write/Erase Protect Region Select (valid when WPDIS = 0) (Page WPFP<5:0> through Configuration Words erase/write protected)
#pragma config WPCFG = OFF // Write/Erase Protect Configuration Region (Configuration Words page not erase/write-protected)

// CONFIG4H
#pragma config WPDIS = OFF // Write Protect Disable bit (WPFP<5:0>/WPEND region ignored)

// running this program will make
// a 1MHz signal avaliable
// on RA6 to be checked with a
// oscilloscope

VOID main( VOID )
{
    clockInit();
    timerInit();

    // set RA6 as digital output
    TRISAbits.TRISA6 = DIGITAL_OUTPUT;

    // turn led off
    LATAbits.LATA6 = 0;

    while(1);
}
```

timer.h

```
#ifndef TIMER_H
#define TIMER_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

VOID timerInit( VOID );
VOID timerReloadRegister( VOID );

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif /* TIMER1US_H */
```

timer.c

```
#include "defs.h"
#include "processor.h"
#include "interrupts.h"
#include <p18cxxx.h>

PRIVATE UINT16 lastTimerRegisterValue_ = 0;

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
PRIVATE VOID writeTMR0Register_( const UINT16 regValue )
{
    UINT16_VAL value;
    value.Val = regValue;

    TMR0H = value.byte.HB;
    TMR0L = value.byte.LB;

    lastTimerRegisterValue_ = regValue;
}

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
VOID timerReloadRegister( VOID )
{
    writeTMR0Register_( lastTimerRegisterValue_ );
}


/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
VOID timerInit( VOID )
{
    UINT16 timerRegValue;
    UINT32 clockTimerFreq = 0;
    UINT32 nTicks = 0;

    const UINT32 clockSystemFreq = CLOCK; // CLOCK = 48000000
    const UINT16 prescalerValue = 256;
    const UINT16 resolution = 65536;
    const UINT16 timerPeriodInMs = 1;

    interruptsDisableGlobal();

    //! configure the timer 0 for 16 bit mode and prescaler of 256
    T0CONbits.TMR0ON = 0; //! turn off
    T0CONbits.T08BIT = 0; //! select the 16 bit mode
    T0CONbits.T0CS = 0; //! internal clock
    T0CONbits.T0SE = 0; //! src edge select bit (0->1)
    T0CONbits.T0PS = 0b111; //! 1/256 prescaler
    T0CONbits.PSA = 0; //! prescaler is assigned

    clockTimerFreq = (UINT32)(clockSystemFreq / ( 4 * prescalerValue ));
    nTicks = (UINT32)((timerPeriodInMs * clockTimerFreq) / 1000);
    timerRegValue = (resolution - nTicks + 1);

    writeTMR0Register_( timerRegValue );

    INTCONbits.TMR0IF = 0; //! clear the interrupt flag
    INTCONbits.TMR0IE = 1; //! enable timer0 interrupt

    T0CONbits.TMR0ON = 1; //! turn on

    interruptsEnableGlobal();
}
```

interrupts.h

```
#ifndef INTERRUPTS_H
#define INTERRUPTS_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

VOID interruptsDisableGlobal( VOID );
VOID interruptsEnableGlobal( VOID );

VOID interruptsEnablePeripheral( VOID );
VOID interruptsDisablePeripheral( VOID );

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif /* INTERRUPTS_H */
```

interrupts.c

```
#include <usart.h>
#include "defs.h"
#include "processor.h"
#include "interrupts.h"
#include "timer.h"


// prototype needed
VOID high_isr (VOID);

/*
 * For PIC18 devices the high interrupt vector is found at
 * 00000008h. The following code will branch to the
 * high_isr function to handle interrupts that occur at
 * the high vector.
 */
#pragma code high_vector=0x08
VOID interrupt_at_high_vector( VOID )
{
  _asm GOTO high_isr _endasm
}

#pragma code /* return to the default code section */

#pragma interrupt high_isr
VOID high_isr (VOID)
{
    // USART1 interrupt handling code
    if( PIR1bits.RC1IF )
    {
        /* Clear the RX interrupt flag for USART1*/
        PIR1bits.RC1IF = 0;
    }

    // timer 0 interrupt handling code
    if( INTCONbits.TMR0IF )
    {
        // actual interrupt handling
        if( CLEAR == PORTAbits.RA6 )
        {
            LATAbits.LATA6 = SET;
        }
        else if( SET == PORTAbits.RA6 )
        {
            LATAbits.LATA6 = CLEAR;
        }

        // reloads last timer register value
        timerReloadRegister();

        // re-enable interrupt
        INTCONbits.TMR0IF = 1;
    }
}

VOID interruptsDisableGlobal( VOID )
{
    // disables all interrupts
    INTCONbits.GIEH = 0;
}

VOID interruptsEnableGlobal( VOID )
{
    // enables all interrupts
    INTCONbits.GIEH = 1;
}

VOID interruptsEnablePeripheral( VOID )
{
    // enables peripheral interrupts
    INTCONbits.PEIE = 1;
}

VOID interruptsDisablePeripheral( VOID )
{
    // enables peripheral interrupts
    INTCONbits.PEIE = 0;
}
```

Can anyone please, help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please explain what is wrong, you've explained what you want, and posted a wall of code. What isn't working?

Comment: I intended to have a 1kHz waveform on RA6 but I got a 13kHz with the scope. Likely I'm setting up the timer wrong but I can't find the error.

Comment: Not familiar with C18 but in out compiler, the math function provides a result with resolution related to the operands.  You appear to be re-casting the result to UINT32 after this result is obtained.  As a quick check, try declaring all of your variables as UINT32 so all of the integer math is done in this resolution.

Comment: I fixed things the way @JohnBirckhead told and also fixed a obvious bug in clearing the interrupt bit. Now I'm getting a 512Hz waveform.

Answer (score 1):

I figured that I made a number of mistakes:

1. I was supposed to expect a 500Hz waveform for a 1ms timer because the pin will toogle *every* edge (raising and falling);
2. There is an obvious bug in the interrupt routine that clears the interrupt flag: the TMR0IF bit should be set to 0, not to 1
3. The calculations for the timer register are here for reference. This code is correct for me:

```
VOID timerInit( VOID )
{
    UINT16 timerRegValue;
    UINT32 timerClock = 0;
    UINT32 nTicks = 0;

    const UINT32 prescalerValue = 256;
    const UINT32 resolution = 65536;
    const UINT32 timerPeriodInMs = 1;

    interruptsDisableGlobal();

    //! configure the timer 0 for 16 bit mode and prescaler of 256
    T0CONbits.TMR0ON    = 0;                //! turn off
    T0CONbits.T08BIT    = 0;                //! select the 16 bit mode
    T0CONbits.T0CS      = 0;                //! internal clock 
    T0CONbits.T0SE      = 0;                //! src edge select bit (0->1)     
    T0CONbits.T0PS      = 0b111;            //! 1/256 prescaler
    T0CONbits.PSA       = 0;                //! prescaler is assigned   

    timerClock = (CLOCK / ( 4 * prescalerValue ));
    nTicks = ((timerPeriodInMs * timerClock) / 1000);
    timerRegValue = (UINT16)(resolution - nTicks);

    writeTMR0Register_( timerRegValue );

    INTCONbits.TMR0IF   = 0;            //! clear the interrupt flag
    INTCONbits.TMR0IE   = 1;            //! enable timer0 interrupt        

    T0CONbits.TMR0ON    = 1;            //! turn on

    interruptsEnableGlobal();    
}
```

Now, I'm a getting a shiny 501Hz waveform in the scope! Thank you all for the tips.